# Dynamically build a treeview in a separate component (Not updating)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a tree view in a component. The groups with which I'm calling my `<Hierarchy/>` are updating dynamically, which naturally means that I will have to re-render the component on update.

Thus far I have the following code:

```
export default function Hierarchy(groups) {

    const buildHierarchy = (groups) => {
            return groups.map(obj => {
                return (<React.Fragment key={obj.id}>
                    {
                            <li>{obj.name}</li>
                    }
                    {
                        obj.children.length > 0 && <ul>{buildHierarchy(obj.children)}</ul>
                    }
                </React.Fragment>
                )
            })
    }
    return (
        <ul>
            {(groups.length > 0) && buildHierarchy(groups)}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

The problem here is however, that I'm unable to even get the HTML which the component is supposed to return, that is: I'm actually only getting the first `<ul>` element.

My initial thought was to add the returned HTML from the `buildHierarchy()` function - But I feel that this may not be correct.

Therefore, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here as to achieving dynamic rendering of my treeview - And thus returning the actual tree view representation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
{
obj.children && obj.children.length > 0 && <ul>{buildHierarchy(obj.children)}</ul>
}
```